# Electrostatic Discharge Protection on Arduinos

Tags: breadboard

I have been using Arduino for quite some time without providing any kind of ESD protection. Does the Arduino have on board ESD protection?

Comment: What does the documentation tell you?

Comment: Check the Arduino documentation, that will probably tell you with words. Alternativly you could check the schematic of the Aruduino board you're using, and see what it has there.

Comment: Almost certainly not. What's the point in protecting the inputs to a bare board where people can touch any point? You can't protect every single trace on the board, that would result in a system where ESD protection took up half the board area.

Comment: ohkk, I did check the documentation and schematic of arduino but such a thing is not mentioned there. But, I came across the datasheet of atmega 328 maybe it will give me a better insight. Thanks for your comments

Comment: *Does the arduino have on board ESD protection?* The chips on the board will have ESD protection. As long as you're not purposely exposing the board to excessive ESD events, that protection is enough. Next time, do more research on what is ESD, what does a protection circuit look like etc, what does ESD mean to a user like me. Before asking here.

Comment: Just use ESD protection, better safe than intermittent